# How to track clicks on bottoms: pageviews vs. events on hybrid app

Tags: google-analytics

I have some categories on my website that I need to track. I want to focus on all the bottoms inside 'My profile' section of an e-commerce hybrid app. The goal is to know how many people clicked on those bottoms and how many people arrived to the destination. To track the second one I am using directly the number of sessions that arrived to those specific URLs.

My questions comes when I have been asked if we should use event tracking or pageview tracking. I think we cannot generate a pageview from a click on a bottom, so a event tracking should be implement on this case. Is this assumption correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat correct.

Technically, you can track both events and pageviews on both clicks and pageloads. Triggers don't enforce the type of an event.

In your case, we typically track both: the click event and the subsequent pageview.

This is somewhat overlapping, but really helps when the url changes, or when the CTA changes. Also helps to see how people navigated to the page when there are suddenly multiple routes.